# Field elements in quiver and relations

Tags: representation-theory, quiver

Let $A=KQ/I$ be a quiver algebra such that the admissible ideal $I$ contains only the field elements $0,1$ and $-1$.

> Question: Is it true for every basic idempotent $e$ that the algebra $eAe$ is isomorphic to a quiver algebra such that the admissible ideal $I$ contains only the field elements $0,1$ and $-1$?

> Question: Is it true in case $A$ is QF-3 and $e$ is such that $eA$ is the basis version of a minimal faithful projective-injective $A$-module?

Comment: Asked [here on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/369804/64073).